# Aligning vertically absolute element larger than container in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, vertical-alignment, absolute

I finally got the problem where my search-fu is not enough. I made some gallery carousel with fixed height and width with image list inside (displaying one li at time). Images are positioned absolute (with `margin:auto` etc) inside relative `li` element.

Images often are larger than its container which has `overflow:hidden`. Images have `max-width:100%` It creates a desired effect that smaller images are centered within container and larger (higher) are cropped which can be opened for full version.

```
.gallery-items>li {
padding:0;
margin:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
}
.gallery-items>li img {
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:auto;
max-width:100%;
max-height:none;
height:auto;
width:auto;
position:absolute;
}
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/fW63c/1/

It works great (center of the image is in the center of container) in IE8, IE9, Opera 12/15, Chrome but in Firefox the larger images start with the beginning of the container (like it would have `top:0`. Does anyone have any idea how to make it work in FF (preferably just using css) . Thanks in advance for any solution, Fafel

Comment: But it does have `top: 0;` - isn't that what your css is telling it to do?

Comment: Please create a fiddle.

Comment: Perhaps FF has the proper standards interpretation however all other browsers treat it differently than FF. It is hard to say why  top:0 is more important than bottom:0 when there is not space for margins.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fW63c/1/

Comment: That's a weird behavior, I spent couple of minutes but I didn't figure it out, finally I used a FireFox CSS hack, you might want to consider: http://jsfiddle.net/fW63c/9/

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it if you don't have to support IE8 or older is to translate the image vertically. This method works in all major browsers, including IE9+:

```
img {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6n2vu7zd/1/

Answer (score 1):

This one has been troubling me quite a bit, but eventually I found that setting `top: -100%;` and `bottom: -100%;` will have the desired effect.

#### Normally the following will work just fine:

```
.child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

But in Firefox, if the parent is not as tall as the child it will simply decide to align them at the top. But this will work:

```
.child2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: -100%;
    bottom: -100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

#### I created a demo to demonstrate:

There are two examples, the first will be wrong in Firefox but both will look fine in Chrome, Edge, and IE.

```css
.child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.child2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -100%;
  bottom: -100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.parent {
  margin: 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img width="75" heigh="75" class="child" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=6e4af45f4d66">
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <img width="75" heigh="75" class="child2" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=6e4af45f4d66">
</div>
```